# Запрос JOIN и COUNT

Tags: mysql, join, count

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN user ON user_id = users
LEFT JOIN news ON user = users
WHERE data_id =9
```

Как в этом же запрос посчитать сколько `comments.id` для каждого `user.user_id` если `user.user_id == comments.users`
Если вам не понятен вопрос не тыкайте - а просто попросите уточнить.

Comment: user вообще не нужен в запросе, если там только ID, который вы берете из comments. так же не ясно зачем клеит ьеще и некую news которая может повлиять на конечное кол во записей. т.е. `select users, count(1) from comments group by users` уже даст кол-во комментов по каждому users

Comment: @Mike в этом запросе все четко, используются данные из всех таблиц. Но вот не хватает еще количество комментов `comments.id` для каждого юзера. не трагедия конечно но хотелось бы получить эти данные. В реале это будет выглядеть как комменты к новости, в которой для каждого юзера будет выведено его общее количество комментов по сайту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM comments C
  LEFT JOIN user U ON U.user_id = C.users
  LEFT JOIN news N ON N.user = C.users
  LEFT JOIN (select users, count(1) as user_com_cnt
               from comments
              group by users) CN ON CN.users = C.users
 WHERE data_id = 9
```

К сожалению данный запрос может тормозить, т.к. каждый раз будет собирать статистику по всем комментариям всех пользователей. Более разумным может быть периодическое вычисление подобной статистики и сохранение этого количества в отдельном поле в таблице users. А еще лучше, вести это количество в таблице users триггерами на добавление/удаление записей в comments.

Comment: `Every derived table must have its own alias` я так понял мне от этого не куда не убежать, и придется воспользоватся советом?

Comment: Это из за того что колонки одинаково в двух таблицах называются. Вообще является правилом хорошего тона дать всем таблицам короткие алиасы и указывать все имена колонок с ними. Расставил как смог

Comment: Запрос на 10 комментов занял ` [1] => 0.0040194988250732` конечно по мере роста буду следить за этим параметром. Спасибо большое

Comment: исправьте опечатку `LEFT JOIN news N ON N.user = C.users` система не дает меньше 6 ти символов править :)) И ответ будет принят, лучше уже как по мне некуда.

Comment: @wwwplaton ok :)